# Asking for wordpress elementor css to be fetched in react app

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress

My React app is not fetching the WordPress built-in CSS, not custom one, but made with Elementor. It is only fetching the data through Axios.

I am making a React + WordPress website. I am fetching my data from WordPress through Axios like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Posts = () => {
    const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let url = 'http://localhost/frontva/wp-json/wp/v2/pages';
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            setPages(res.data);
        });
    }, []);

    console.log('pages', pages);

    return (
        <div >
            {pages.map((page, index) => (
                <div key={page.id}>
                    {index === 2 && (
                        <>
                            {/* <h1 className='text-5xl animate-bounce'>{page.title.rendered}</h1> */}
                            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content.rendered}}></p>
                        
                        </>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Posts;
```

In this way my pages are rendering. I have three pages and I am showing only at index 2 which is the homepage. My React app is only fetching the data, it is not fetching the Elementor CSS. I have built the whole homepage through Elementor and didn't use any custom CSS. When I am fetching the data, it is not showing any CSS, only the data is fetched, with no CSS, no responsiveness. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: https://salehmubashar.com/blog/different-ways-to-add-css-in-react-js